# ajax form updating specific div not working from $("#formName").submit();

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an ajax form, with a submit button. When I press that submit button it loads my content and puts it in my specified div.

```
<form action="/ControllerName/ActionName" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#contentDiv" id="myForm" method="post">
<input type="submit" />
<div id="contentDiv">
    <p>No content has been loaded yet</p>
</div>

<nav>
   <li id="pager-next" class="next "><a href="#"><span aria-hidden="true">Next</span></a></li>
</nav>

</form>
```

The code above works fine when I press the submit button, it loads the content and puts it it in the contentDiv. But when I press the pager-next, it loads the content but it puts it in an entirely new page instead of inside the contentDiv.

```
<script>
$("#pager-next").click(function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   $("#myForm").submit();
})
</script>
```

Any suggestions how I can get it working so when I press the pager-next it will load it inside the contentDiv instead of a new page?

Comment: you need ajax for that

Comment: `$("#filterForm").submit();` will submit the form, which then sends the form to its action (`action="/ControllerName/ActionName"`). To prevent this, listen to submit event on the form, prevent its submission and send the form data through xhr.

Answer (score 0):

what you should do is disable the form submit..

```
 <form action="javascript:void(0)" id="myForm" ....>
     <input type="submit value="submit" />
     <div id="dynamic"></div>
 </form>
```

then in your javascript

```
 $(document).on('submit','#myForm',function{
      $.ajax({
          url: "/ControllerName/ActionName",
          success: function(response) {
              $("#dynamic").html(response);
          }
      });
 })
```

**EDIT**

since you can't edit the form you could just add return false in the submit event like

```
$(document).on('submit','#myForm',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // do ajax here
    return false;
});
```

as edited I added `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: Is it also possible without editing the form? As I generated the form with asp.net:

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "ContentDiv" }, new { id = "myForm" }))
    {

Comment: A clean way is to not remove the action url. Just listen to the submit event. And then in the ajax handler, use the action value as url. By this, this works even at clients that has javascript disabled.

Comment: yes it is possible.. since you cannot edit the form you can just return false

Comment: my answer is updated please include "return false" and it must be after the ajax for the ajax to execute

Comment: It still doesn't work... When I press the submit button I just want the normal post functionality. When I press my pager-next list item it should just do exactly the same as when I pressed the button before.

Comment: what is the response of your ajax ?

Comment: It keeps on resubmitting the form. The first time I get the values from my input, after that the values are null.

This is my javascript:
$(document).on('submit', '#myForm', function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/ControllerName/ActionName",
        method: "POST",
        success: function (response) {
            $("#contentDiv").html(response);
        }
    })

    return false;
})

Comment: what does your /ControllerName/ActionName do ? does it need input parameters ?

Comment: added `e.preventdefault();` also revise `function()` to `function(e)` ..

Comment: Still the same. Maybe it works when I execute a click on that button from javascript?

Comment: $('#submitButton').trigger('click') worked for me (after adding id=submitButton) to the button of course.